# to achieve this step Modify it to pass a value prop to Square

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, redux

- I am new to react.
- I am trying to achieve this step Modify it to pass a value prop to Square.
- can you tell me why its not working, when I click in box I dont see x
- working code https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/gWWQPY?editors=0010
- not working code http://codepen.io/texirv/pen/qmLVOZ?editors=0010

providing code below

```or-tag-here
   renderSquare(i) {
    return <Square value={ this.state.squares[i] } />;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

In the non working code, you had spelt it `onclick`.  This is incorrect, it's meant to be `onClick`.

```
<button className="square" onClick = {() => this.setState({value: 'X'})}>
```

This fork now shows it working, with that change: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eWxdoG?editors=0010